# Supposedly easy one-sided test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a very easy question but I feel like some information is missing:

The point estimate of a coefficient $\beta$ (in linear regression) is $-1$ and he corresponding estimated asymptotic standard error is $\frac{3}{7}$. The level of confidence is 0.99. Then what to do with the following:
$$
H_0: \beta = 0,\quad H_1:\beta < 0\quad 
$$
The solution is to reject $H_0$, but why? I have no number of observations... . The $F$ statistic is
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{3}{7}} = \frac{7}{3}
$$
if I am not mistaken.

But since I have no number of obs. (or do I) how do I judge this?

And does the solution change if $H_1: \beta \neq 0$? I guess so - in a two sided test $H_0$ *could* at least be kept...

Or should I look up the values in a $t$-table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According "the corresponding estimated asymptotic standard error is..." I believe you can assume that $n \ge 6$, then you can use the $t$ table in order to verify the answer. Your t statistics is $t_{stat}= \frac{-1-0}{3/7}=-7/3$  (where $F$ is its square, which doesn't really matter here)

Comment: Okay, why is it $-\frac{7}{3}$ and not $\frac{7}{3}$? Could you give me the corresponding formula for the $t$-statistic? And is there anything different if $H_1:\beta >0$. I am very new to this unfortunately...

Comment: I've edited the answer. The formula is $(\hat \beta - \beta_{H_0})/ \hat s.d(\hat \beta))$. The formula is the same for one (in whatever direction)  and two sides alternative, however,  you need to compare to the corresponding t value from the table, which differs according to $H_1$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. So if $H_1:\beta<0$ then I have to look up $df=1$ and $\alpha = 0.01$? Or $\alpha=0.99$?

Comment: Or I guess that $df$ is $z$....

Comment: It depends on the form of your table, but for the extended two sided table, then you have to look at something like: one tail, and $0.01$.  For a table with only positive values, then one tail and $0.99$, just add minus to the t-value from the table. The df, I guess, at least $30$.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks!